# Plupload: Passing a session variable to upload.php in order to update an avatar upload in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, session

Beginner question:
To manage his profile, the registered member must be able to upload / modify an avatar via Plupload plugin.

Only in the upload.php file, to update the database ('users' table), I need the user id given by `$_SESSION['auth']` variable.

This variable exists in profile.php : `var_dump($_SESSION['auth'])` gives:

```
C:\wamp\www\graf\profile.php:24:
object(stdClass)[1]
    public 'id' => string '22' (length=2)
    public 'username' => string 'johndoe' (length=6)
    public 'email' => string 'john@doe.com' (length=17)
    public 'password' => string '$2y$10$nwS.6PlyuH7NQnRuPdRJnuLmPSJK/gzmcWomHYz5Uk3SOkDutnLQ.' (length=60)
    public 'confirmation_token' => null
    public 'confirmed_at' => string '2016-11-29 12:27:40' (length=19)
    public 'reset_token' => null
    public 'reset_at' => null
    public 'remember_token' => null
    public 'avatar' => string 'John-Doe.png' (length=12)
```

But I can not transmit `$_SESSION['auth']` to upload.php. Please let me know how.

profile.php:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){ session_start(); }
require_once('inc/functions.php'); 
require_once('inc/db.php');
reconnect_from_cookie();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html > 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Member Profile</title>
    <link href="css-up/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <script src="js-up/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="plupload">        
        <div id="droparea">
            <p>Drag and drop your files here</p>
            <span class="or">ou</span>
            <a href="#" id="browse">Browse</a>
        </div>
        <div id="filelist">
            <?php foreach(glob('uploads/*.*') as $v):?>
                <div class="file">                
                    <img src="<?php  echo $v; ?>">
                    <?php  echo basename($v); ?>                
                    <div class="actions">
                        <a href="<?php  echo basename($v) ?>" class="del">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script src="js-up/plupload/plupload.full.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="js-up/plupload/moxie.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="js-up/main.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
//var sessId = '<?php echo $_SESSION['auth']['id'] ; ?>';    
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes          : 'html5,flash',
    container         : 'plupload',
    browse_button     : 'browse',
    drop_element      : 'droparea',
    url               : 'upload.php',
    flash_swf_url     : 'js-up/plupload/Moxie.swf',
    multi_selection   : false,
    multipart         : true,
    urlstream_upload  : true,
    multipart_params  : {directory:'test'},
    max_file_size     : '1mb',
    resize            : {width:320,height:240,quality:90},
    filters           : [{ title: 'images', extensions:'JPEG,JPG,PNG,GIF'}]
});

uploader.bind('Init',function(up, params){  
    if(params.runtime!='html5'){
        $('#droparea').css('border','none').find('p,span').remove();
    }
});

uploader.bind('UploadProgress',function(up, file){
    $('#'+file.id).find('.progress').css('width',file.percent+'%');
});

uploader.init();   

uploader.bind('FilesAdded',function(up,files){    
    var filelist=$('#filelist');
    for(var i in files){
        var file= files[i];
        filelist.prepend('<div id="'+file.id+'" class="file">'+file.name+' ('+plupload.formatSize(file.size)+')'+'<div class="progressbar"><div class="progress"></div></div></div>');
    }
    $('#droparea').removeClass('hover');
    uploader.start();
    uploader.refresh();
}); 

uploader.bind('Error',function(up,err){
    alert(err.message);
    $('#droparea').removeClass('hover');
    uploader.refresh();
});
uploader.bind('FileUploaded',function(up, file, response){    
    data = $.parseJSON(response.response);
    if(data.error){
        alert(data.message);
        $('#'+file.id).remove();
    }else{
        $('#'+file.id).replaceWith(data.html);
        /*
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "upload.php",
        data: "sessId="+sessId
        }); 
        */            
    }
});

jQuery(function($){ 
    $('#droparea').bind({
        dragover:function(e){
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        },
        dragleave:function(e){
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        }
    });

    $('.del').on('click',function(e){   
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem =$(this);
        if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete this image?')){
            $.get('upload.php', {action:'delete',file:elem.attr('href')});
            elem.parent().parent().slideUp();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

upload.php :

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){ session_start();  }

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']== 'delete'){
    unlink('uploads/'.$_GET['file']);
    die();
}
require_once('inc/functions.php'); 
require_once('inc/db.php');
reconnect_from_cookie();

$extensions_allowed = array('.JPEG','.jpg', '.PNG','.GIF' ); 
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'], '.');  
if(!in_array($extension, $extensions_allowed))  {      
    alert('Only files in these formats are accepted: png, gif, jpg, jpeg ');        
}else{        
    $file=$_FILES['file'];    
    $name=$file['name'];
    if(filesize($file['tmp_name']) > 1000000){
        die('{"error":true, "message": "The file is too large. Please upload a picture below 1 Mo."}');
    }        
    if(file_exists('uploads/'.$name)){
        die('{"error":true, "message": "Image already exists"}');
    }  

    $name = strtr($name,'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ','~');        
    $name = preg_replace('/([^.a-zA-Z0-9]+)/i', '-', $name);        
    $u = mt_rand(0,1000000)."_".$name;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.$u );

    //This request works
    $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET avatar=? WHERE id=22 ")->execute([$u]) ;  
    $pdo = null;        
    /* This doesn't work
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
    $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET avatar=? WHERE id=? ')->execute([$u,$user->id]) ;        
    $pdo = null;
    */
    $v='uploads/'.$u;
    $html='<div class="file"><img src="'.$v.'" />'.basename($v).'<div class="actions"><a href="'.basename($v).'" class="del" >&times;</a></div></div>';
    $html=str_replace('"','\\"',$html);
    die('{"error":false, "html": "'.$html.'"}');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `session_start()` to resume the session. Just remove the `if` before it so that it starts every time. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Replace

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){ session_start();  }
```

By

```
session_start();
```